# Can't get div to align with image

Tags: html, css

I'm building responsive website and have a problem with aligning div.button to align with bottom side of the image.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/E22nq/

I would like to have div.button aligned with image, and dynamically hide text in div#text so that the width of the div.content is dependent on image (image height depends on the width of the browser).

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="left">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="text">...</div>
        <div class="button">BUTTON</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
}

#left {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

#right {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I would like to have button under text, but bottom left aligned with the image.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
#right {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```